# tcl file is unable to get environment variable which is set through code

Tags: c++, linux, windows, tcl, xilinx

I have set the environment variable through my code using putenv. I am reading the environment variable through tcl file. It seems , in windows this is showing the following 
Error   : can't read "env(myvar)": no such variable, 
 no such variable
    (read trace on "env(myvar)")
    invoked from within
 "puts $env(myar)"

but in Linux the error is not coming.

putenv is used to set environment variable
$env() is used in tcl file to get env.

Comment: "not working" is not a useful problem description.

Comment: Problem has been edited, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is known, and is caused by the fact that if we synchronize more exactly there's a much larger performance penalty for all accesses to environment variables from Tcl, and that's a much more common use case than the one you have where you are changing the environment variable from C code. (The `putenv()` system call doesn't give us anything we can efficiently hook to detect the changes, so we end up having to reassemble the whole `env` array from scratch; this was found to be a significant bottleneck.)

The simplest workaround is for you to create a little extra command in Tcl (but written in C) that wraps the `getenv()` call directly so that you can use that with environment variables that you suspect may have been changed behind Tcl's back.

```
int WrapGetEnv(ClientData ignored, Tcl_Interp *interp, int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        // Probably ought to be a better error here
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }
    char *var = argv[1];
    char *val = getenv(var);
    if (val != NULL) {
        Tcl_SetResult(interp, val, TCL_DYNAMIC);
    }
    return TCL_OK;
}

// ... in the right place do this ...
Tcl_CreateCommand(interp, "getenv", WrapGetEnv, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Handling all the error cases is left as an exercise…

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment!!.

Comment: But this issue seems to come in windows as well as Linux. But in my case, issue is only coming with windows. Is there any reason for the same ?